# Processing XML based DSL

Tags: xml, svg, swi-prolog

SWI-Prolog has plenty to offer as a generalized XML processor.

`library(sgml)` for read/write XML structured formats, `library(xpath)` for navigation and more... but if I attempt to read a SVG, that it is valid XML, I get the message:

```
ERROR: SGML2PL(xml): ...my_file...svg:2: file "...myfile.path.../http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd" does not exist
```

false.

Does anyone has an hint on this? I'd also want to rewrite the eventually modified file content preserving of course the distinctive DTD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, saving locally the DTD file I got with curl, I can request to SGML library to use it.

```
...
    new_dtd(svg, DTD),
    path(Dir, 'svg11.dtd', DtdFile),
    load_dtd(DTD, DtdFile),

    path(Dir, 'html_labels.svg', SvgFile),
    load_structure(SvgFile, [Svg], svg:[dtd(DTD), dialect(xmlns), xml_no_ns(quiet)]),
...
```

As I said, I got `svg11.dtd` in this way

```
$ curl http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd > svg11.dtd
```