# How to convert the dojox.charting.Chart to a PNG image for user to export?

Tags: java, dojo, webkit, png, batik

There is a new requirement in my project being developed by DOJO that user can able to export the chart as a PNG image. I had a research and found 2 ideas:

1, Try to find a appropriate method in DOJO API to export directly to a PNG image (Because I get similar with Ext JS, which offers API method for export to image), but DOJO chart is without a method to do it.

Using DOJO API like dojox.fx or dojox.gfx to draw image, but these cannot generate images. So I give up on this way.

2, Using the third-party plugin to do it. First, I can get the chart's surface content by method 'dojox.gfx.utils.toSvg(chart.surface).then', and then use plugin Batik from Apache to convert the SVG content into a PNG image. Following is my trying code:

```
dojox.gfx.utils.toSvg(chart.surface).then(function(svg) {
    var args = {
        url : "chart/doExportChart.action",
        content : {
            svgContent : svg
        },
        handleAs : "json",
        load : function(response) {
            // Do something like exporting the responded image.
        },
        error : function(error) {
            // Error handling
        }
    };

    dojo.xhrPost(args);
    }, 
    function(error) {
        // Error handling
    }
);
```

And the method doExportChart do something like:

```
JPEGTranscoder t = new JPEGTranscoder();

// Set the transcoding hints.
t.addTranscodingHint(JPEGTranscoder.KEY_QUALITY, new Float(.8));

// Create the transcoder input.
String svgURI = new File("c:/sample.svg").toURL().toString();
TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(svgURI);

// Create the transcoder output.
OutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream("c:/sample.jpg");
TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(ostream);

 // Save the image.
 t.transcode(input, output);

// Flush and close the stream.
 ostream.flush();
ostream.close();
```

Content of SVG sample.svg as below:

```
svg xmlns=httpwww.w3.org2000svg width=1200 height=589defsrect fill=rgb(255, 255, 255) fill-opacity=1 stroke=none stroke-opacity=0 stroke-width=1 stroke-linecap=butt stroke-linejoin=miter stroke-miterlimit=4 x=41.5 y=13.666666666666666 width=1142 height=528.5 fill-rule=evenoddg transform=matrix(1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000,541.16666667)gpolyline fill=none fill-opacity=0 stroke=rgb(204, 204, 204) stroke-opacity=1 stroke-width=1.7 stroke-linecap=butt stroke-linejoin=miter stroke-miterlimit=4 points=42.50000000 14.66666667 90.00000000 242.63573883 137.50000000 191.97594502 185.00000000 126.84192440 232.50000000 242.63573883 280.00000000 201.02233677 327.50000000 159.40893471 375.00000000 541.16666667 422.50000000 343.95532646 470.00000000 220.92439863 517.50000000 146.74398625 565.00000000 224.54295533 612.50000000 240.82646048 660.00000000 110.55841924 707.50000000 249.87285223 755.00000000 161.21821306 802.50000000 195.59450172 850.00000000 320.43470790 897.50000000 318.62542955 945.00000000 282.43986254 992.50000000 286.05841924 1040.00000000 349.38316151 1087.50000000 210.06872852 1135.00000000 286.05841924 1182.50000000 329.48109966 stroke-dasharray=none polyline fill=none fill-opacity=0 stroke=rgb(191, 19, 19) stroke-opacity=1 stroke-width=1.5 stroke-linecap=butt stroke-linejoin=miter stroke-miterlimit=4 points=42.50000000 14.66666667 90.00000000 242.63573883 137.50000000 191.97594502 185.00000000 126.84192440 232.50000000 242.63573883 280.00000000 201.02233677 327.50000000 159.40893471 375.00000000 541.16666667 422.50000000 343.95532646 470.00000000 220.92439863 517.50000000 146.74398625 565.00000000 224.54295533 612.50000000 240.82646048 660.00000000 110.55841924 707.50000000 249.87285223 755.00000000 161.21821306 802.50000000 195.59450172 850.00000000 320.43470790 897.50000000 318.62542955 945.00000000 282.43986254 992.50000000 286.05841924 1040.00000000 349.38316151 1087.50000000 210.06872852 1135.00000000 286.05841924 1182.50000000 329.48109966 stroke-dasharray=none ggrect fill=rgb(255, 255, 255) fill-opacity=1 stroke=none stroke-opacity=0 stroke-width=1 stroke-linecap=butt stroke-linejoin=miter stroke-miterlimit=4 x=0 y=0 width=42.5 height=590 fill-rule=evenoddrect fill=rgb(255, 255, 255) fill-opacity=1 stroke=none stroke-opacity=0 stroke-width=1 stroke-linecap=butt stroke-linejoin=miter stroke-miterlimit=4 x=1182.5 y=0 width=18.5 height=591 fill-rule=evenoddrect fill=rgb(255, 255, 255) fill-opacity=1 stroke=none stroke-opacity=0 stroke-width=1 stroke-linecap=butt stroke-linejoin=miter stroke-miterlimit=4 x=0 y=0 width=1201 height=14.666666666666666 fill-rule=evenoddrect fill=rgb(255, 255, 255) fill-opacity=1 stroke=none stroke-opacity=0 stroke-width=1 stroke-linecap=butt stroke-linejoin=miter stroke-miterlimit=4 x=0 y=541.1666666666666 width=1201 height=49.83333333333333 fill-rule=evenoddgline fill=none fill-opacity=0 stroke=rgb(51, 51, 51) stroke-opacity=1 stroke-width=1 stroke-linecap=butt stroke-linejoin=miter stroke-miterlimit=4 x1=42.5 y1=541.1666666666666 x2=1182.5 y2=541.1666666666666 stroke-dasharray=none ggline fill=none fill-opacity=0 stroke=rgb(51, 51, 51) stroke-opacity=1 stroke-width=1 stroke-linecap=butt stroke-linejoin=miter stroke-miterlimit=4 x1=42.5 y1=541.1666666666666 x2=42.5 y2=14.666666666666666 stroke-dasharray=none line fill=none fill-opacity=0 stroke=rgb(102, 102, 102) stroke-opacity=1 stroke-width=1 stroke-linecap=butt stroke-linejoin=miter stroke-miterlimit=4 x1=42.5 y1=427.1821305841924 x2=36.5 y2=427.1821305841924 stroke-dasharray=none text fill=rgb(51, 51, 51) fill-opacity=1 stroke=none stroke-opacity=0 stroke-width=1 stroke-linecap=butt stroke-linejoin=miter stroke-miterlimit=4 x=32.5 y=430.91546391752576 text-anchor=end text-decoration=none rotate=0 kerning=auto text-rendering=optimizeLegibility font-style=normal font-variant=normal font-weight=normal font-size=7pt font-family=Tahoma fill-rule=evenodd100textline fill=none fill-opacity=0 stroke=rgb(102, 102, 102) stroke-opacity=1 stroke-width=1 stroke-linecap=butt stroke-linejoin=miter stroke-miterlimit=4 x1=42.5 y1=246.25429553264598 x2=36.5 y2=246.25429553264598 stroke-dasharray=none text fill=rgb(51, 51, 51) fill-opacity=1 stroke=none stroke-opacity=0 stroke-width=1 stroke-linecap=butt stroke-linejoin=miter stroke-miterlimit=4 x=32.5 y=249.9876288659793 text-anchor=end text-decoration=none rotate=0 kerning=auto text-rendering=optimizeLegibility font-style=normal font-variant=normal font-weight=normal font-size=7pt font-family=Tahoma fill-rule=evenodd200textline fill=none fill-opacity=0 stroke=rgb(102, 102, 102) stroke-opacity=1 stroke-width=1 stroke-linecap=butt stroke-linejoin=miter stroke-miterlimit=4 x1=42.5 y1=65.32646048109962 x2=36.5 y2=65.32646048109962 stroke-dasharray=none text fill=rgb(51, 51, 51) fill-opacity=1 stroke=none stroke-opacity=0 stroke-width=1 stroke-linecap=butt stroke-linejoin=miter stroke-miterlimit=4 x=32.5 y=69.05979381443295 text-anchor=end text-decoration=none rotate=0 kerning=auto text-rendering=optimizeLegibility font-style=normal font-variant=normal font-weight=normal font-size=7pt font-family=Tahoma fill-rule=evenodd300textgsvg
```

And then run above code error encounters:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderException: null
Enclosed Exception:
Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.transcode(XMLAbstractTranscoder.java:136)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(SVGAbstractTranscoder.java:156)
    at com.ibm.crl.poc.util.PocImageUtil.main(PocImageUtil.java:142)
```

I do the second solution follow the official example from http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/transcoder.html. I have no idea and hope anyone out there who gives me guidance. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to support older browsers, using svg is simply not an option. Most browser versions past 2006 has some basic support though - however as for Internet explorer IE8 and older require a plug-in to render SVG content.

**@ Batik Exception**; it looks like an external source parse failed (there are bugs to search for this issue and styling syntaxes). Its difficult to stop any in the onliner above, but try downloading the xmlns and serve it on same domain as the sample.svg (or try leave it out) as [proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448424/processing-xml-based-dsl)

Maybe the approach is slightly off, unless you require the image to have excact same look and feel. You could make use of the series, used for chart and instead of conversion of SVG, create plot via for [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) or similar.

Either way, you cannot expect javascript to generate PNG, the algorithms involved are... encoumbersome :)

The last option there is, is having your chart rendered in a frame, leaving the page very simple and quickly rendered (create a dojolayer to avoid 100+ requests). Then, grab a 'snapshot' of this frame from serverside, once client requests an image export. This will ensure that the support for SVG is present and give serialized results. As example:

clientside:

```
<iframe
     width=700
     height=400
     src="chart/doRenderChart.action?unid=howto_identify_graph"></iframe>
```

serverside, once user clicks 'export':

```
doExportAction(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
   String chart = req.getParameter('url') 
         = "chart/doRenderChart.action?unid=howto_identify_graph";
   int width = 700;
   int height = 400;
   File f = File.createTempFile("prefix",null,myDir);
   String tmpfile = f.getName();
   f.delete();
   Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/path/to/bin/wkhtmltoimage "+
        "--crop-h " + height + 
        " --crop-w " + height + " " +
          chart + 
        " -f png " + 
          tmpfile
   ); 
   p.waitFor();
   // get and serve 'tmpfile' contents
}
```

Here's the project for [WKHtmlToXX](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)